# Как получить эскиз для файла?

Tags: xcode, macos

Finder умеет получать эскизы видео, изображений и даже текстовых документов. Насколько я понял, для этого он как-то использует Quick Look. Но вся документация, которую я нашел, описывает то, как генерировать эскиз для своего типа файлов, а не получать уже созданные.

Пожалуйста, подскажите хотя бы направление, в котором надо копать.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение тут - https://code.google.com/p/maccode/source/browse/trunk/Snippets/QuickLook/#QuickLook%2FNSImageQuickLook

Правда пришлось внести незначительные изменения, но поскольку их предложил внести сам xcod я воздержусь от их указания :)